# Parameter as Left Hand Side Operator LIKE JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I’m trying to execute the following query: (Using EclipseLink 2.5.2, MySQL 5.5)

```
em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Region r WHERE (:pattern LIKE CONCAT(r.pattern, '%'))")
            .setParameter("pattern", "EU.FR.PR")
            .getResultList();
```

(Background: I’m trying to find all super regions of a region. So the super regions of `EU.FR.PR` would be `EU.FR` and `EU`.)

However this throws the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value
>   of type class java.lang.String for parameter pattern with expected
>   type of class java.lang.Boolean from query string

The [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbvg) state that

> A LIKE expression determines whether a wildcard pattern matches a string.

The most relevant parts of my `Region` class are:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Region.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Region r")
public class Region implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String pattern;

    public Region() {
    }

    public String getPattern() {
        return this.pattern;
    }

    public void setPattern(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

}
```

Here is some sample data from the table:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | pattern     |
+----+-------------+
|  3 | EU          |
|  5 | EU.FR       |
|  6 | EU.FR.AL    |
| 13 | EU.FR.LU    |
| 14 | EU.FR.PR    |
| 15 | EU.FR.PR.BA |
| 16 | EU.FR.PR.CA |
| 17 | EU.FR.PR.PA |
| 18 | EU.FR.RH    |
| 19 | EU.FR.RH.TV |
| 20 | EU.FR.RO    |
+----+-------------+
```

So why should I pass a boolean?

---

Directly concatenating the region into the query (`"SELECT r FROM Region r WHERE ('" + theRegion + "' LIKE CONCAT(r.pattern, '%'))"`) gives the expected results but this is not something I want to do in production. Is this a bug in EclipseLink?

Comment: Paste your `Region`source please.

Comment: Does this work: `SELECT r FROM Region r WHERE (r.pattern LIKE CONCAT(:pattern, '%'))`? Or this: `SELECT r FROM Region r WHERE r.pattern LIKE :pattern || '%'`? The bind variable needs to be on the right-hand side of the expression.

Comment: @MickMnemonic This has a completely different meaning. This would for instance  find  `EU.AT.ST.GR` but neither `EU.AT` nor `EU`.

Comment: Could you post some sample data from your table, so that it's easier to work with the SQL.

Comment: Seems like what you need is `SUBSTR` instead: `SELECT r FROM Region r WHERE SUBSTR(r.pattern, 1, 2) = SUBSTR(:pattern, 1, 2) AND LENGTH(r.pattern) < LENGTH(:pattern)` How is a super region defined? How long can the pattern be for these values?

Comment: @MickMnemonic The pattern is limited to 5 parts. The super regions of `EU.FR.PR` would be `EU.FR` and `EU`. So by removing the last alphabetic characters and the full stop you get a super region. Doing this again gets you the next super region.

Comment: How is the `ID` column defined in the DB -- is it a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Neither, it’s `int`. (The DB is MySQL 5.5.)

Comment: No, sorry; I meant the `PATTERN` column. But I think the problem is that the `LIKE` condition does not work with a bind variable on the left hand side ("search value"). You probably have to rewrite this using `SUBSTR` or some regex function that's available in MySQL.

Comment: @MickMnemonic The pattern column is `varchar`. Do you know if JPA has got some escape method? I think I’ll go with concatenating it myself. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: fwiw, I tested your code in Hibernate 4.7 and it works fine. It generates this MySQL: "from cities city0_ where 'EU.FR.PR' like concat(city0_.name, '%')"

Comment: @TerrenceCurran Wow, thanks. Looks like a bug in EclipseLink. I'll try to report it tomorrow.

Comment: I stumbled into the same issue today. I wound up using something like `SELECT r FROM Region r WHERE 1 = LOCATE(r.pattern, :pattern)`. Works fine.